# What should be the labels for subword tokens in BERT for NER task?

Tags: python, named-entity-recognition, bert

For any NER task, we need a sequence of words and their corresponding labels.
To extract features for these words from BERT, they need to be tokenized into subwords.

For example, the word `'infrequent'` (with label B-count) will be tokenized into `['in', '##fr', '##e', '##quent']`. How will its label be represented?

According to the BERT [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1810.04805.pdf), "We use the representation of the first sub-token as the input to the token-level classifier over the NER label set".

So I assume, for the subwords `['in', '##fr', '##e', '##quent']` , the label for the first subword will either be this `['B-count', 'B-count', 'B-count', 'B-count']` where we propagate the word label to all the subwords. Or should it be `['B-count', 'X', 'X', 'X']` where we leave the original label on the first token of the word, then use the label “X” for subwords of that word.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: as far as I've understood, you should map only the root of the word that gets "tokenized" in subwords. I'm facing similar issues with a WSD task. After BERT, you should make a custom layer that removes the subwords... how to do so is still a mystery to me

Comment: Yes, we need to combine the subword token embeddings using some method (averaging over them?) and get rid of the dummy (X) subword token labels. I need to figure that out too yet.

Comment: @adjective_noun Hi, have you figured it out yet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Method 2 is the correct one.

Leave the actual label of the word only in the first sub-token, and the other sub-tokens will have a dummy label (which in this case is 'X'). The important thing is that when calculating the loss (e.g., CELoss) and metrics (e.g., F1), this 'X' labels on the sub-tokens are not taken into account.

This is also the reason why we don't use method 1 is that otherwise, we would be introducing more labels of the type `[B-count]` and affecting the support number for such a class (which would make a test set no longer comparable with other models that do not increase the number of labels for such class).

Comment: Hi, could you please give a source of your claim please?

Answer (score 0):

i am using huingface for NER.
To solve this problem, you can refer to this website:https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/tasks/token_classification
Specifically, the code for aligning labels and final evaluation is as follows

```
def tokenize_and_align_labels(examples):
    tokenized_inputs = tokenizer(examples["tokens"], truncation=True, is_split_into_words=True)

    labels = []
    for i, label in enumerate(examples[f"ner_tags"]):
        word_ids = tokenized_inputs.word_ids(batch_index=i)  # Map tokens to their respective word.
        previous_word_idx = None
        label_ids = []
        for word_idx in word_ids:  # Set the special tokens to -100.
            if word_idx is None:
                label_ids.append(-100)
            elif word_idx != previous_word_idx:  # Only label the first token of a given word.
                label_ids.append(label[word_idx])
            else:
                label_ids.append(-100)
            previous_word_idx = word_idx
        labels.append(label_ids)

    tokenized_inputs["labels"] = labels
    return tokenized_inputs

import numpy as np

labels = [label_list[i] for i in example[f"ner_tags"]]


def compute_metrics(p):
    predictions, labels = p
    predictions = np.argmax(predictions, axis=2)

    true_predictions = [
        [label_list[p] for (p, l) in zip(prediction, label) if l != -100]
        for prediction, label in zip(predictions, labels)
    ]
    true_labels = [
        [label_list[l] for (p, l) in zip(prediction, label) if l != -100]
        for prediction, label in zip(predictions, labels)
    ]

    results = seqeval.compute(predictions=true_predictions, references=true_labels)
    return {
        "precision": results["overall_precision"],
        "recall": results["overall_recall"],
        "f1": results["overall_f1"],
        "accuracy": results["overall_accuracy"],
    }
```